# Loose hose inside SmartBidet

Tags: gfci

I have a SmartBidet 2000 that keeps tripping the GFCI outlet. I opened it up to see what was wrong with the electronics and noticed a loose hose (water tube?) that wasn't connected to anything on one side. Other side is connected to the tank. Other hoses coming out of the tank are connected on both ends. I don't know if I did that on opening or it was like that. No clue where it goes and can't find on the internet. HELP! After closing it back up and reattaching it, it now trips the outlet when I plug it in.
[image]
[image]

Comment: what model is it

Comment: do you realize that you are asking questions about an unknown tube in an unknown bidet?

Comment: I am still just trying to understand why a bidet needs to be smart.  Not like you need to use it half way across the country or let google know when you use it.

Comment: Please [Edit] your question and add some pics to show us what you see.

Comment: @crip659 Maybe as a joke to fire it up on some unexpecting  occupant..

Comment: Is this a new install or a new problem.

Comment: New problem. As I stated, I inherited the bidet when I bought the place and it was working fine for a couple of months. Then it started tripping the outlet. I now reset the outlet every time I use it as it will be tripped every time I go in.

Comment: That hose could be a breather/vacuum breaker hose.  Does any water come out of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see a video of someone disassembling a Smartbidet here:  https://youtu.be/8rLctWL-IVI?t=123

At around 2:08 you can see this same hose in roughly the same position where you are holding it, but is resting in the upper right area.  It does not appear to be connected to anything.